# Sort cell input from customized cell in viewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, uitableview

I have a ViewController in which a tableView and a button "sort" is integrated. 
The cells of this tableView are customized in another class called "customizedCell".

When the ViewController is loaded, a label (riskTitle: UITextView! in CellCustomized) in the tableView is filled with the items stored in the array (RiskTitles_Plan = String in ViewController). My code below has some values hard coded for this array.

What I am trying to do now is to store the numbers generated by two pickerViews in the label "riskFactor: UILabel!" in an array (RiskFactor_Plan -> RiskFactor_Int). When the user clicks on the button sort, the values in my array have to be sorted and the rows in the tableView will be loaded in a new order (smallest to biggest number or vise versa).

This is my code (unnecessary code is deleted).

**Swift 3 - ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var RiskTitles_Plan = [String]()
    var RiskFactor_Plan = [String]()
    var RiskFactor_Plan_Int = [Int]()

    var sortBtn = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        RiskTitles_Plan = ["my cat","my dog","my sheep","my cow","my fish"]

        sortBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Sort"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        sortBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RiskPlan.sortAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(sortBtn)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return RiskTitles_Plan.count
    }

 /////// Here comes the interesting part ///////

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CellCustomized

        RiskFactor_Plan.append(cell.riskFactor.text!)
        cell.riskTitle?.text = RiskTitles_Plan[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = myColorsClass.darkCyan()

        for i in RiskFactor_Plan_Int {
            let stringItem: String = String(i)
            RiskFactor_Plan.append(stringItem)
        }

        cell.riskFactor.text! = RiskFactor_Plan[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func sortAction(_ sender:UIButton!) {

        for i in RiskFactor_Plan {
            let intItem: Int = Int(i)!
            RiskFactor_Plan_Int.append(intItem)
        }

        RiskFactor_Plan_Int = RiskFactor_Plan_Int.sorted{ $0 < $1 }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**Swift 3 - CellCustomized:**

```
import UIKit

class CellCustomized: UITableViewCell {

    var myColorsClass = myColors()
    var myStylesClass = myStyles()

    @IBOutlet weak var riskTitle: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var riskFactor: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) // the common code is executed in this super call

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    } // nib end

}
```

The code above results in the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` for code line: `let intItem: Int = Int(i)!` in ViewController when the sort button in clicked.

My problem is to figure out

- how to save the generated values in riskFactor: UILabel! in an array (-> RiskTitles_Plan = String) during runtime. I guess the array needs to be appended whenever the label in the table is updated with a generated value
- how to convert the string array (-> RiskTitles_Plan = String) to an integer array (-> RiskTitles_Plan_Int = Int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the context of your problem I tried to replicate in a project so this is how I do it, hopefully it can help you.

## Result:

[image]

## Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  
  var risks = Array<(title: String, factor: Int)>()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    risks.append(("my cat", 0))
    risks.append(("my dog", 0))
    risks.append(("my sheep", 0))
    risks.append(("my cow", 0))
    risks.append(("my fish", 0))
  }
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return risks.count
  }
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    
    let riskTitle = risks[indexPath.row].title
    let riskFactor = risks[indexPath.row].factor
    
    cell.titleLabel.text = riskTitle
    cell.factorLabel.text = String(riskFactor)
    cell.index = indexPath.row
    
    
    cell.onFactorValueChanged = { [unowned self] newFactorValue, atIndex in
      self.risks[atIndex].factor = newFactorValue
    }
    
    return cell
  }
  
  @IBAction func sortRisksBasedOnFactor(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    risks.sort { (riskA, riskB) -> Bool in
      return riskA.factor > riskB.factor
    }
    
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

---

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  
  @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var factorLabel: UILabel!
  var index = 0
 
  var onFactorValueChanged: (Int, Int) -> Void = { _ in }
 
  @IBAction func generateFactor(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    factorLabel.text = String(random(min: 1, max: 10))
    onFactorValueChanged(Int(factorLabel.text!)!, index)
  }
  
  func random(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    guard min < max else {return min}
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(1 + max - min))) + min
  }
  
}
```

Comment: This solution is working as long as the table consists only of the two fields. This is due to the fact that it is not the row that is sorted, but the values. This leads to the problem that when I have some more field (e.g. I also have a pickerView in my CustomizedCell class as well, the fields are not part of the sorting procedure and the table values are all mixed up after pressing the sort button. I extended your example in regard to the other fields in my CustomizedCell class, but then I have problems with the calculated label value. Maybe I need a completely different attempt.